# Excel =Column() giving #NAME? error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`=COLUMN()`

This was working fine yesterday but today it gives me `#NAME?` as the result rather than the column that the formula is in.

[image: ColumnError]

What is going on today that's different from yesterday?

---

Edit: Even more bizarrely if I enter the `=COLUMN()` using the fx (insert function) button then it works fine.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Correct-a-NAME-error-13416b02-2a46-4677-817f-608d0b98c734

Comment: That doesn't help at all. I had already consulted that and it doesn't cover it.

Comment: What is the content of the cell, after you insert it with the fx button?

Comment: It reads exactly the same in the formula bar. If I use the fx button in A2 it will correctly return 1 instead of `#NAME?`.

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in a new blank workbook? And you haven't got a UDF in a module anywhere using the same name?

Comment: The original issue was in a resolution I was giving to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721866/creating-a-map-generator-in-excel). If I open a new workbook and paste into A1: `="Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(IF(ROW()-3<1,1,ROW()-3),IF(COLUMN()-3<1,1,C‌​OLUMN()-3))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()+3,COLUMN()+3)` (which is part of the formula) it works fine for the first 3 columns but fails on the fourth. If I then pare down the formula to find the issue it is around `COLUMN()`. If I then use fx in another cell it's fine. It seems to be the second COLUMN()-3 specifically...

Comment: Strange enough: if I copy your formula from your comment over into my Excel then I can reproduce the error. Yet, if I type in the formula from scratch myself then I don't have any problems. So, I made a 1:1 character compare of your copied text to what I entered using `AscW`. It seems that your formula contains some non-standard characters such as `ChrW(8203)` and `ChrW(8204)`. So, give this a try and let me know if it works: `="Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(IF(ROW()-3<1,1,ROW()-3),IF(COLUMN()-3<1,1,C‌​OLUMN()-3))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()+3,COLUMN()+3)` (looks the same but isn't).

Comment: If I paste that in it gives a "We found a problem with this formula" type error and highlights the double quote after the colon. If I delete that and type in a double quote its then fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for **copying** over the formula from your Excel here. Otherwise I never would have found it.

The problem is that you have some non-standard characters in your formula which do not show. Doing a 1:1 comparison of your formula with a formula I have written myself into Excel using `AscW()` I came up with the following result:

```
Character     Letter        AscW(yours)   AscW(mine)
 1            =              61            61 
 2            C              67            67 
 3            ?              8204          79 
 4            ?              8203          76 
 5            O              79            85 
 6            L              76            77 
 7            U              85            78 
 8            M              77            40 
 9            N              78            41 
10            (              40            
11            )              41
```

As you can see, your formula is by two letters longer. There is a `AscW(8204)` and a `AscW(8203)` between the `C` and the `O` of the word `Column`. These characters do not show. Yet, they are there.

Also note, that this is not the case everywhere in the `Column()` you have posted in the above question. The first `=COLUMN()` at the top of your post is fine and works normally. Furthermore, the first `Column` in this formula

```
="Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(IF(ROW()-3<1,1,ROW()-3),IF(COLUMN()-3<1,1,C‌​OLUMN()-3))&":"‌​&ADDRESS(ROW()+3,COLUMN()+3)
```

is fine. Merely the second `column` in this formula contains these extra characters. So, I'd like to suggest that you re-type the formula (manually) without copying it from anywhere and you should be fine.

Comment: how did you spot that? *impressed*

Comment: I did not "see" that (as it cannot be seen). This is experience only. I worked for a large corporation with Excel users all around the world: English Excel, Arabian Excel, EU Excels, Chinese Excel, and even Russian Excel. The latter is the worst because some letters in the Cyrillic alphabet are (visually) the same to those in the Latin alphabet. Yet, Excel knows the difference. For example: `ChrW(1089)` will give you a **Cyrillic** letter which look like a Latin `c`. If you were to write the formula `= Column()` with that letter then it won't work either. Same with `ChrW(1086)` instead of `o`.

Comment: Since Russians work a lot (in an international setting) on English / Russian documents simultaneously they sometimes use these (and many more letters) interchangeably without noticing it. This can cause problems such as the one above. Yet, it makes matters even worse when keeping a database of customers (including their names and addresses) written with Cyrillic and Latin alphabets all mixed-up. This is when you have to take *Master Data Management* to the next level.